# Nested foreach in odt Templates

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops, odt

I am reworking a time management tool which creates Reports.
The data is written to an .odt file. The Data looks something like this:

Projects Array holds a Users Array. Users Array holds a days Array, days Array holds a times Array.

I have a report that outputs

ProjectName

| Date | User | time | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `$time['date']` | `$user['name']` | `$time['sum']` | `foreach($time as $t){$t['comment']}` |

This works via multiple foreach loops in an .odt table

```php
{foreach($projects as $project):}
    {$project['name']}
    {foreach($aProject['users'] as $aUser):}
        {foreach( $aUser['days'] as $aDay ):}
            {$aDay['date']}  | {$aUser['name']} |{$aDay['sum']} h | 
            {foreach($aDay['comment'] as $comment):}
                {$comment['comment']}
            {endforeach}    
        {endforeach}
    {endforeach}
{endforeach}
```

The Output looks something like this:
ProjectName

| Date | User | time | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Day1 | User1 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day1 |
| Day2 | User1 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day2 |
| Day3 | User1 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day3 |
| Day1 | User2 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day1 |

I would like the Output to look like this:

ProjectName

| Date | User | time | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Day1 | User1 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day1 |
| Day1 | User2 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day1 |
| Day2 | User1 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day2 |
| Day2 | User2 | sum of times | comment from each time entry on Day2 |

Is there an easy way to accomplish this inside the .odt foreach loops?
I would rather avoid reworking the whole data setup for this specific report.

Comment: How do you fill these arrays?

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is a predefined getDay() function which puts all the data, in the selected Time frame, into $time. Then there is a foreach over $time to put the Data into the different arrays. getDay() uses an auto join over tbl_users, tbl_project and tbl_time  and returns all that as nested arrays to $time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished it by adding an additional subarray which holds the needed data on basis of date. In there i had a WokingUsers array for each Day, with the corresponding times.